# jQuery IF statement (Only if a web browser on a desktop) not a mobile device / iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a easy way with jQuery to essentially have a jQUery/JS if statement along the lines of:

```
IF User is on a web Browser on a desktop... not a mobile device / iPad
```

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. What makes desktops special?

Comment: Desktops behave somewhat differently. In particular, the "tap" event (from jQuery Mobile) does not include any positional information when fired on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Although not really recommended to use this, here it is:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

excerpt:

Because $.browser uses navigator.userAgent to determine the platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself. It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely where possible. The $.support property is available for detection of support for particular features rather than relying on $.browser.